# Rendering correctly to create a new page

Tags: php, yii2

In my website user rating and feedback text area are in messaging page of the website, which I would like to separate them from the messaging page and create a new page for them. Below you can see the piece of code about rating and feedback from the message controller file.

```
// send feedback
public function actionSendFeed() {

    $this->layout = $this->view_dir.'/Rate-Supplier'; 

    $first_message = $this->getFirstChain(Yii::$app->request->post('chain', false));

    $mail_data = $this->getMessageReceiver($first_message);

    // save feedback if not empty

    $feed_data = Yii::$app->request->post('Feedback', false);
    if($feed_data['rate'] >= 1){
        $feed_model = new Feedback();
        $feed_model->customer_id = $mail_data['send_to'];
        $feed_model->author_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $feed_model->subject = $first_message->subject;
        $feed_model->seen = 0;
        $feed_model->created_at = time();

        if(!$feed_model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) || !$feed_model->save()){
             Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', Yii::t('alerts', 'err_send_feedback'));
        }else{
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('alerts', 'feedback_sent'));

            // send email to customer about new feedback
            \common\components\helpers\MailHelper::send(
                    'new_feedback',
                    [SH::get('support_email') => Yii::$app->name],
                    $mail_data['email_to'],
                    ['{supplier_name}', '{buyer_name}', '{text}'], 
                    [$mail_data['name_to'], Yii::$app->user->identity->name, $feed_model->text]
            );            
        }
    }
    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}
```

I have tried to render but wasn't successful in that. Please share your opinion with me how can I render correctly so I can create a new separate page for rating and feedback.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To render page in view file from controller you have to use below code :

```
return $this->render('index', [ 'arr' => Yii::$app->request->referrer ]);

// index = 'Your View File Name'
```

Comment: Naushil Jain, Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please tell me in this case what is going to be the link of the new page. Lets say the view file name is "index".

Comment: Suppose if your controller name is Sitecontroller and you are adding one file in "views/site/response.php" for your HTML then you have to add only "response" instead of index.

Comment: Sorry, but I am afraid I couldn't find it in that way.